# Why can functions be pickled, but not modules?

Tags: python, pickle, python-2.x, python-module

I noticed that when my object contains an explicit reference to a module, `pickling` it will fail because of this.

However, if I stick a reference to a function from that module into my object instead, it can be picked and unpickled successfully.

How come Python can pickle functions, but not modules?

Comment: @Tommy modules are objects

Comment: isinstance(math, object) => True

Comment: correct, sorry. I was trying to get at, what is the desired result of pickling a module? The code? The state?

Comment: *The code?* -- by this logic, pickling functions is the bigger problem, hence the title of my Q. *The state?* -- other objects store state just as modules do.

Comment: @MaxB: Other objects also have the ability to define `__reduce__` (or related higher level pickling methods) on their classes, but the module type can't do that, because the possible things to pickle/unpickle would differ too much from module to module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they didn't code support for it. C level types (and even modules written in Python are implemented with a C level type) require `pickle` support to be coded explicitly.

It's not very easy to determine what should be pickled if a `module` is allowed to be pickled; importing the same name on the other side would seem simple, but if you're actually trying to pickle the module itself, the worry would be that you want to pickle module state as well. It's even more confusing if the module is a C extension module, where module state may not even be exposed to Python itself, only used internally at the C layer.

Given that usually you want specific things from a module, not the whole module (which is usually not referenced as state, just imported at the top level), the benefits of supporting pickling for modules are limited, and the semantics are unclear, they haven't bothered to implement it.